How to right-align a line in align environment?
This LaTeX code
\begin{align*}
        \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u \, \varphi &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
        + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(z) \, \varphi(z) \, dz \\
        &= \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(x)-u(z)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz \hfill \\
        &\hfill + \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(z)-u(x)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz \\
        &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{\bparens{u(x)-u(z)} \bparens{\varphi(x)-\varphi(z)}}{|x-z|^{n+2s}}  \, dx \, dz.
\end{align*}

looks like this:

I would like the third line to be aligned to the right. How could I do it? I would prefer not to use \qquad repeatedly or \hspace. Thanks a lot.

Perhaps related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287127/right-align-a-line-in-align-environment?rq=1

Right aligned to the text block, or just right aligned to the width of the widest element in the align construction? Likely the latter, correct?

You already got nice suggestions, but please make a note on future, always post your MWE from \documentclass to \end{document}

@MadyYuvi I will, thank you.

You could measure the widest element (right-hand side) and then place the third line right-aligned inside a box of equal width. This can be automated with the below \eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>} macro. It sets <stuff> inside a box that is aligned based on <align> (options are right, left or center) and has a maximum width across all of the same <tag>.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bparens}[1]{\bigl( #1 \bigr)}

\begin{document}

% Original layout
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u \, \varphi 
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
      + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(z) \, \varphi(z) \, dz \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(x) - u(z)}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz \hfill \\
    &\hfill + \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(z) - u(x)}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{\bparens{u(x) - u(z)} \bparens{\varphi(x) - \varphi(z)}}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}}  \, dx \, dz.
\end{align*}

% Updated layout using \eqmathbox
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u \, \varphi 
    &\eqmathbox[RHS][l]{{} = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
      + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(z) \, \varphi(z) \, dz} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(x) - u(z)}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz \hfill \\
    &\eqmathbox[RHS][r]{{} + \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(z) - u(x)}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz} \\
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{\bparens{u(x) - u(z)} \bparens{\varphi(x) - \varphi(z)}}{|x - z|^{n + 2s}}  \, dx \, dz.
\end{align*}

\end{document}


I wouldn't recommend a full rightward shift of the third row. A simple indentation of the row by \quad or \qquad may be all that's needed. And, I'd insert a bit of extra whitespace after row 1 and row 3 in order to provide a visual represenation of the fact that rows 2 and 3 "belong together". This may be done by adding \jot (default value: 3pt) of extra vertical whitespace at the end of rows 1 and 3.
A separate issue: If "P.V." denotes Cauchy's "principal value operator", I'd declare a macro called \PV via \newcommand{\PV}{\mathop{\mathrm{PV}}\!} in the preamble and replace all instances of \text{P.V.} with \PV. This change will streamline the handling of spacing matters associated with this operator. (Many thanks to @egreg for bringing the meaning of "P.V." to my attention and for suggesting a specific form for \PV!)

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\usepackage{amssymb}    % for '\mathbb' macro
\newcommand{\PV}{\mathop{\mathrm{PV}}\!} % thanks, Enrico!
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\bparens[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\int_{\R^n}\! (-\Delta)^s u \varphi 
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n}\! (-\Delta)^s u(x) \varphi(x) \, dx 
      +\frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n}\! (-\Delta)^s u(z) \varphi(z) \, dz 
    \\[\jot] % insert a \jot of vertical whitespace
    &= \frac{1}{2} \PV \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} 
       \frac{u(x)-u(z)}{\abs{x-z}^{n+2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz 
    \\
    &\qquad
      +\frac{1}{2} \PV \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} 
       \frac{u(z)-u(x)}{\abs{x-z}^{n+2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz 
    \\[\jot] % insert a \jot of vertical whitespace
    &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} 
       \frac{\bparens{u(x)-u(z)}\bparens{\varphi(x)-\varphi(z)}}%
            {\abs{x-z}^{n+2s}} \, dx \, dz\,.
\end{align*}

\end{document}


PV is not a variable, but an operator, for Cauchy’s principal value. I’d go with \mathop{\mathrm{PV}}\!

Thanks! I’ve updated my answer to reflect this piece of information.

A right alignment with respect to the text box can be achieved with the multlined environment from the mathtools package, setting the width to \linewidth. But with your equation and standard article margins, the output isn't very good

In this case you can set manually a smaller width, for example with0.6\linewidth :

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand\bparens[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u \, \varphi &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
        + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(z) \, \varphi(z) \, dz \\
        &=
          \begin{multlined}[t][0.6\linewidth]
            \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(x)-u(z)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz \hfill \\
            + \frac{1}{2} \text{P.V.} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(z)-u(x)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz
          \end{multlined}\\
        &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{\bparens{u(x)-u(z)} \bparens{\varphi(x)-\varphi(z)}}{|x-z|^{n+2s}}  \, dx \, dz.
\end{align*}

\end{document}


Did you check if the equations fit within \columnwidth?

@Mico No you right. I'll delete this answer.

Do please keep the first solution. Just maybe change \begin{multlined}[t][\linewidth] to \begin{multlined}[t][0.55\linewidth] so that rows 2 and 3 continue to "belong together", visually speaking.

@Mico Done. Thanks for your suggestion.

You're most welcome! :-) +1.

You can do it with IEEEeqnarray
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\pvint}{\operatorname{PV}\!\!\int}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bparens}[1]{\bigl(#1\bigr)} % my crystal ball suggests

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u \, \varphi 
&=& 
\frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx 
  + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} (- \Delta)^s u(z) \, \varphi(z) \, dz
\\[1ex]
&=&
\frac{1}{2} \pvint_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(x)-u(z)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(x) \, dx \, dz
\\
&&
 \hfill{}
  + \frac{1}{2} \pvint_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n} \frac{u(z)-u(x)}{|x-z|^{n+2s}} \varphi(z) \, dx \, dz
\\[1ex]
&=& \frac{1}{2} \int_{\R^n} \int_{\R^n}
    \frac{\bparens{u(x)-u(z)} \bparens{\varphi(x)-\varphi(z)}}{|x-z|^{n+2s}}  \, dx \, dz.
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}

Note the command for the principal value integral. It's better to use such a personal command, because it allows you to keep a uniform look and also to change the typesetting at the last moment.
The \operatorname object will use the correct spacing for the integral; then we want to remove the thin space between operators, but in this specific case, due the the shapes of V and of the integral, it's better to use two of them.
The {} after \hfill is needed in order for the + to have the correct space after it

